# Xamarin.forms app not building after updating Visual Studio. Could not find file AppName.dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

After i updated Visual Studio 2019 Community (ver. 16.4.5) and Xamarin.Forms to latest stable builds, I'm no longer able to build my app. Now when i try to build it, i get 2 identical errors like this:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\Didakticke testy\Didaktick-testy\DDKTCKE\DDKTCKE\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ČJ-Didaktické testy.dll'.
File name: 'D:\Didakticke testy\Didaktick-testy\DDKTCKE\DDKTCKE\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ČJ-Didaktické testy.dll'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FilterAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   DDKTCKE.Android
```

I already tried :

- Deleting Obj and Bin folders
- Cleaning solution
- Rebuilding solution
- Killing process msbuild.exe

Comment: Did you rebuild solution?

Comment: @AdloremAd You mean that your project can run successfully before, then you update Visual studio 2019, you have this issue when you run project again? If yes, I suggest you can update Visual-studio 2019 and try it again.

Comment: Its not my project ^^

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT Yes, it worked perfectly before. I can't update VS anymore as I have the newest version. Even tried repairing VS with no change.

Comment: @Adream I suggest you can create new blank project to run, see if there is still have this issue, if not, I suggest you can report this issue at github xamarin.forms.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT I created a new blank Xamarin.Forms project, then when I tried to build it this error popped up : 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Xamarin.Tools.Zip.ZipEntry.Rename(System.String). I think VS is completely messed up, probably will have to reinstall it.

Comment: @Adream yes, I suggest you can reinstall visual studio, may there are some issue when you installed this tool.